# List parsing with special input/optional arguments

Tags: macros, optional-arguments, parsing

I’d like to parse a list where the elements can be given as either `[<pre>]<text>[<post>]`, where `<pre>` and `<post>` are optional, or `(<special text>)`. I found a solution where everything works if `<text>` is a single token but not if it’s a word.

So an input like

```
\mylist{1,[a]2,3[b],[c]4[d],(5)}
```

I get and desire an output like

[image: right result]

but with

```
\mylist{111,[a]222,333[b],[c]444[d],(555)}
```

I get this

[image: wrong result]

while desiring this output

[image: desired result]

I also tried to use `{<text>}` instead of `<text>`, i.e. put the element in curly braces, but it doesn’t help in all cases. Furthermore I’d prefer to not use braces do delimit the element.

<strike>The separator printing doesn’t work well too.</strike>

Here’s what I’ve got so far

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}

\makeatletter

\usepackage{etoolbox,xparse}
\def\cflist@printsep{%
   \ifcflist@sep\quad$\bullet$\quad\fi
}
\def\cflist@none#1{%
   \@ifnextchar[{\cflist@printsep[#1]\cflist@last}{%
      \cflist@printsep
      [#1]%
   }%
}
\def\cflist@first[#1]#2{%
   \@ifnextchar[{\cflist@printsep\cflist@both[#1]{#2}}{\cflist@printsep${}_{#1}$[#2]}%
}
\def\cflist@last#1[#2]{%
   #1${}_{#2}$%
}
\def\cflist@both[#1]#2[#3]{%
   ${}_{#1}$[#2]${}_{#3}$%
}
\def\cflist@extra(#1){\cflist@printsep[#1]${}_E$}
\newcounter{cflist@cnt}
\newif\ifcflist@sep
\def\cflist@do#1{%
   \@ifnextchar({%
      \cflist@extra%
   }{%
      \@ifnextchar[{\cflist@first}{%
         \cflist@none%
      }%
   }#1%
   \stepcounter{cflist@cnt}%
   \ifnum\value{cflist@cnt}=0\relax\else
      \cflist@septrue
   \fi
}

\DeclareListParser{\cflist@parser}{,}

\newcommand{\mylist}[1]{%
   \let\do\cflist@do
   \setcounter{cflist@cnt}{0}%
   \cflist@sepfalse
   \cflist@parser{#1}%
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

Single element tokes work fine:\\
\mylist{1,[a]2,3[b],[c]4[d],(5)}

Multiple element tokes don't work:\\
\mylist{111,[a]222,333[b],[c]444[d],(555)}\\
\mylist{aaa,[a]bbb,ccc[b],[c]ddd[d],(eee)}

Multiple element tokens in curly braces don't work either:\\
\mylist{{111},[a]{222},{333}[b],[c]{444}[d],(555)}\\
\mylist{{aaa},[a]{bbb},{ccc}[b],[c]{ddd}[d],(eee)}

Desired result for multiple element tokes:\\
111\quad$\bullet$\quad${}_a$222\quad$\bullet$\quad
333${}_b$\quad$\bullet$\quad${}_c$444${}_d$
\quad$\bullet$\quad555${}_E$
\end{document}
```

The output format is a placeholder for other formatting macros, but I guess it doesn’t affect the problem and make the code a little shorter if I use the dummies here.

### Update

I forgot `\cflist@sepfalse` which causes the superfluous sep at the begin of all lists after the first one

### Updated 2

The real application is to send the list to `\cite` macros of biblatex, so the list

```
aaa,[a]bbb,ccc[b],[c]ddd[d],(eee)
```

should be processed as

```
\cite{aaa}, \cite[][a]{bbb}, \cite[b]{ccc}, \cite[c][d]{ddd}, eee
```

The `(eee)` part should bypass the `\cite` mechanism and printed as is without the parentheses.

Comment: `\mylist{111,[a]222,333[b],[c]444[d],(555)}` is this typed in or added in by other macros i.e., how do you collect the input?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: It is typed by me. So it is very easy to define another input scheme

Comment: I want to call several `\cite` macros (and do some other stuff why I can’t use \cites) with `\mylist`.

Comment: and pre and post always single letters?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: I added an update that shows the application.

Comment: sorry this is a bit confusing, so you only want to remove the () if they exist, the rest of the stream gets passed on?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: I want to be able to bypass the cite macro. To tell the list which items should be bypassed I thought to use parens. The final output will be printed in a frame box, i.e. a TikZ `node`.

Comment: @Tobi besides this being an interesting question why don't you just use biblatex's own multicite commands like `\cites` (see section “ Qualified Citation Lists
” of the biblatex manual)?

Comment: @cgnieder: Hm … Because I need a wrapper to format the list and forgot that this is possible. I’ll post my solution but it misses the ability to specify an element that is not passed to `\cite` like the `(pass)` elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answers (at least partially) the parsing problem. But of course here I'm using specific features of math mode. But the principle should be clear.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\mylist#1{%
  \@for\next:=#1\do{%
    \expandafter\@mylistaux\next[]\@nil
    \@mylist@separator}%
  }
\def\@mylistaux{\@ifnextchar(\@mylistauxi\@mylistauxii}
\def\@mylistauxi(#1)[]\@nil{\@mylist@parentheses{#1}}
\def\@mylistauxii{\@ifnextchar[\@mylistauxiii{\@mylistauxiii[]}}
\def\@mylistauxiii[#1]#2[#3]#4\@nil{\@mylist@brackets{#1}{#2}{#3}}

%% final macros
\def\@mylist@parentheses#1{%
  % do something for the case (xxx)
  $(#1)_{E}$}
\def\@mylist@parentheses#1#2#3{%
  % do something for the case [a]xxx[b]
  % #1 is a, #2 is xxx, #3 is b
  $_{#1}#2_{#3}$
\def\@mylist@separator{\quad$\bullet$\quad}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mylist{1,[a]2,3[b],[c]444[d],(5)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A LaTeX3 implementation that makes clearer how to use the gathered arguments:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_tobi_list_seq
\tl_new:N \l_tobi_last_item_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\mylist}{m}
  {
   \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tobi_list_seq { , }{ #1 }
   \seq_pop_right:NN \l_tobi_list_seq \l_tobi_last_item_tl
   \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tobi_list_seq { \tobi_process:w ##1 [ ] \q_stop \tobi_separator: }
   \exp_after:wN \tobi_process:w \l_tobi_last_item_tl [ ] \q_stop
  }
\cs_new:Npn \tobi_process:w 
  {
   \peek_charcode:NTF ( { \tobi_process_aux_i:w } { \tobi_process_aux_ii:w }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \tobi_process_aux_i:w ( #1 ) [ ] \q_stop
  {
   \tobi_final_parentheses:n { #1 }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \tobi_process_aux_ii:w
  {
   \peek_charcode:NTF [ { \tobi_process_aux_iii:w } { \tobi_process_aux_iii:w [ ] }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \tobi_process_aux_iii:w [ #1 ] #2 [ #3 ] #4 \q_stop
  {
   \tobi_final_brackets:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
  }
%% Final macros
\cs_new:Npn \tobi_final_parentheses:n #1
  {
   $(#1)\sb{E}$
  }
\cs_new:Npn \tobi_final_brackets:nnn #1 #2 #3
  {
   $\sb{#1}#2\sb{#3}$
  }
\cs_new:Npn \tobi_separator: { \quad\textbullet\quad }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

One now has to suitably define `\tobi_final_parentheses:n`, `\tobi_final_brackets:nnn` and `\tobi_separator:`.

It's not necessary to use these names: just use what you prefer; the code might be

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_tobi_list_seq
\tl_new:N \l_tobi_last_item_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\mylist}{m}
  {
   \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tobi_list_seq { , }{ #1 }
   \seq_pop_right:NN \l_tobi_list_seq \l_tobi_last_item_tl
   \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tobi_list_seq { \tobi_process:w ##1 [ ] \q_stop \mylistseparator }
   \exp_after:wN \tobi_process:w \l_tobi_last_item_tl [ ] \q_stop
  }
\cs_new:Npn \tobi_process:w 
  {
   \peek_charcode:NTF ( { \tobi_process_aux_i:w } { \tobi_process_aux_ii:w }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \tobi_process_aux_i:w ( #1 ) [ ] \q_stop
  {
   \mylistelementinparentheses { #1 }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \tobi_process_aux_ii:w
  {
   \peek_charcode:NTF [ { \tobi_process_aux_iii:w } { \tobi_process_aux_iii:w [ ] }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \tobi_process_aux_iii:w [ #1 ] #2 [ #3 ] #4 \q_stop
  {
   \mylistelementinbrackets { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

%% Final macros
\newcommand\mylistelementinparentheses[1]{$(#1)\sb{E}$}
\newcommand\mylistelementinbrackets[3]{$\sb{#1}#2\sb{#3}$}
\newcommand\mylistseparator {\quad\textbullet\quad}
```

so the hard work making macros can be defined as you're accustomed to (the names can be changed, of course).

### EDIT

How to define `\tobi_final_parentheses:n`, `\tobi_final_brackets:nnn` and `\tobi_separator:` for the desired output. As you can see, LaTeX3 syntax allows for very easy management of empty arguments.

```
%% Final macros
% aaa -> \cite{aaa}
% [a]bbb -> \cite[][a]{bbb}
% ccc[b] -> \cite[b]{ccc}
% [c]ddd[d] -> \cite[c][d]{ddd}
% (eee) -> eee

\cs_new:Npn \tobi_final_parentheses:n #1 { #1 }
\cs_new:Npn \tobi_final_brackets:nnn #1 #2 #3
  {
   \tl_if_empty:nTF { #3 }
     {
      \tl_if_empty:nTF { #1 }
        { \cite{#2} }
        { \cite[][#1]{#2} }
     }
     {
      \tl_if_empty:nTF { #1 }
        { \cite[#3]{#2} }
        { \cite[#1][#3]{#2} }
     }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \tobi_separator: {, ~ }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: That's the intermission solution ;-)

Comment: Thanks but I can’t  transfer that to my code. The original application has nothing to do with math; I only used it as a dummy in my example. Your L3 solution makes nothing clearer … I guess its time to learn L3 O:-)

Comment: I added the real application to my question

Comment: @Tobi It's quite easy to adapt the first solution to any setting. I'll make some changes to show how.

Comment: Thanks again. I’ll have a look at it in a few days (No computer for some days …)

Comment: Finally I had the time to analyse you code and after your edit it was easy to adapt it to my application. Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 4):

If a `luatex` solution is ok, then you can try the `lpeg` parser to achieve what you want.

First the `lua` file (save it as `listparsing.lua`). Note that I use `-2` as the first argument to make `tex.sprint` prints thing verbatim. You have to change this value to `-1` to use the standard catcode régime. The parser accepts only words (that is a succession of letters) but it can be easily expanded to other types of word (like e.g. control sequences). An other possible enhancement would be to check for balanced brackets (a bit more difficult, as it implies the use of a real grammar).

```lua
lpeg = require('lpeg')

local P, R, S, C, Cs, V = lpeg.P, lpeg.R, lpeg.S, lpeg.C, lpeg.Cs, lpeg.V
local match = lpeg.match

local space = S(' \n\t')
local lbracket, rbracket = P('['), P(']')
local lparen, rparen = P('('), P(')')
local comma = P(',') * space^0 / ', '

local letter = R('az') + R('AZ')
local word = letter^1

local digit = R('09')
local number = digit^1

local pretextpost = lbracket * C(word) * rbracket * C(word) * lbracket * C(word) * rbracket / function (a,b,c) return string.format('\\cite[%s][%s]{%s}',a,c,b) end
local pretext = lbracket * C(word) * rbracket * C(word) / function (a,b) return string.format('\\cite[][%s]{%s}',a,b) end
local posttext = C(word) * lbracket * C(word) * rbracket / function (a,b) return string.format('\\cite[%s]{%s}',b,a) end
local text = C(word) / function (a) return string.format('\\cite{%s}',a) end
local special = lparen * C(word) * rparen / function (a) return a  end
local pattern = pretextpost + pretext + posttext + text + special

local parser = Cs(pattern * (comma * pattern)^0)

function parse_and_texprint(s)
   return tex.sprint(-2,match(parser,s))
end
```

Then the `tex` file.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\directlua{dofile('listparsing.lua')}
\def\mylist#1{%
  \directlua{%
    parse_and_texprint('#1')}}
\begin{document}
\texttt{\mylist{aaa,[a]bbb,ccc[b],[c]ddd[d],(eee)}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not a final solution, as I think what you are asking can get very complicated, but is indicative of building a finite state machine. For demonstration purposes, I will use `@tfor` to scan the list letter by letter. LaTeX3, I am sure (as egreg's solution shows)  offers better possibilities.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@gather
\newif\if@store
\DeclareRobustCommand\temp{}
\let\@ex\expandafter
\edef\alist{[a]2[b],3[b],[c]4[d],(eee)}
\def\parse#1{%
\@ex\@tfor\@ex\next\@ex:\@ex=#1\do{%
    \@gathertrue\@storetrue
    \if\next,\@gathertrue\@storetrue\def\next{$\bullet$}\fi
    \if\next[\@gathertrue\@storefalse\fi
    \if\next]\@storefalse\@gathertrue\fi
    \if\next(\@gathertrue\@storefalse\fi 
    \if\next)\@storefalse\@gathertrue\fi
    \if@store\edef\temp{\temp\next}\fi
}}
\parse\alist
\temp
\end{document}
```

The advantage of this method, besides being more readable is that you can capture every letter and either store it in a macro or token list or do something else for it. In the example I just removed all the `[]`, the `()` and replaced the commas with `$\bullet`. It will need much more work to achieve what you are after and to make it robust to check for errors and edge cases. A much better and more robust scanner can be build using `\futurelet`. In this respect you might be able to either borrow code from the `soul` package, which has an excellent parser or you can use the `\SOUL@everytoken` macro.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution using the skills of `biblatex`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\cfwrapper}[1]{
   \colorbox{green!50!black}{%
      \color{white}\sffamily
      \textbf{i}\enskip
      #1
   }%
}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cf}[\cfwrapper]{\cite}{, }
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{(#1)}
\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{ }

\begin{document}
Text \cf{kastenholz,hyman}[S. 2]{markey}
\end{document}
```

It works fine for most of all cases but it misses a way to bypass the `\cite` command. Like a list element in parens `(pass it)` in the above question and answers.